# Call function after running an SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

In my SpriteKit game, I want to call a function after running an `SKAction`.

I am assuming it is possible to do with:

```
let node = SKSpriteNode()
...
node.run(<action: SKAction>, completion: <() -> Void>)
```

But I can't figure out what to put into `<() -> Void>` to call a function.

```
func actionDone() {
...
}
```

Comment: You can use *trailing closure syntax*: `node.run(yourAction) { actionDone() }` which might come in handy if you want to do something in addition to calling `actionDone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple, just put in the name of the function without parentheses:

```
node.run(someAction, completion: actionDone)
```

and call it

```
completion()
```

within the body of the `run` method.

---

Or with a parameter

```
func run(action : SKAction, completion:(String)->()) {
    // do the action
    completion("Done")
}

func actionDone(param: String) {
   print(param)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, new year... new denseness... What do you mean by this: "within the action body."?

Comment: I admit the sentence might be a bit misleading. I mean: Call it like in the second example with parameter.

Comment: argh, thank you. I think my cognition suffered from that hangover when blending the naming with syntax. So completion is both the name of the parameter that will be the function that's also named completion, and somewhere else that completion function is defined. Right?

Comment: `completion` is just a parameter label with type `(String)->()` which is a closure passing a string parameter with no return value. Technically a function is a closure so you can pass any function which matches the signature.

Comment: Yes, I get that. What confused me was that you were using completion as both a parameter name AND as the name of the function, and then saying to call it within the body of the run method... and then demonstrated calling it but then said do so inside something. Decompressing and distancing syntax from semantics with everything using common names was doing my head in.